# How to represent flexible/unknown TypeScript data in GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have data that can be represented by the following TypeScript interface:

```js
interface ChangedAttributes {
    [attribute: string]: {
        [field: string]: {
            from: any;
            to: any;
        };
    };
}
```

Each `attribute` has one or multiple objects with, for example, the key: `field` which is associated with an object which has `from` and `to` properties which can be anything, string, boolean, object, etc. There can be one or many `attribute` properties in an object of the `ChangedAttributes` type.

Here is an example of an object that conforms to this:

```js
    const d: ChangedAttributes = {
        second_attribute: {
            disabled: {
                from: false,
                to: true,
            },
            value: {
                from: 'test',
                to: 'test2',
            },
        },
        first_attribute: {
            name: {
                from: 'fred',
                to: 'george',
            },
        },
    };
```

My issue is representing this in GraphQL. Maybe I've reached the limitations of it but it seems like there is not a way to have such a flexible data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your type can be one of several other types then you can use a [union](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/) to define it.

If that's not flexible enough you can always use a [JSON scalar type](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/scalars/json) to represent *any*.

On further reflection it looks like you're implementing a change log. The JSON type might be best suited for that.